# from position not working for .m4a format file using sound manager audio player

Tags: soundmanager2, m4a

I am using Sound Manager audio player with from / to positions to play the audio in web browser (all browsers). It's working fine for `.mp3` files but `'from'` position is not working for `.m4a` files it playing from '0' position, and `'to'` position is working fine for both formats.

Comment: Describing in more details (code / screenshot ...) what you mean by "not working for `.m4a` format files" might help answering the question.

Comment: not working means audio playing from starting even if we defined the start position also